# How to get Color and coordinates(x,y) from Texture2D XNA c#?

Tags: c#, xna, xna-4.0

What i'm trying to do is check perfect-pixel colision with 2 textures which have black edges for example: one of this texture is a circle the second one can be triangle or rectangle.

this my code which give me only array of color without coordinates which i need

```
Color[] playerColorArray = new Color[texturePlayer.Width * texturePlayer.Height];
Color[] secondColorArray = new Color[secondTexture.Width * sencondTexture.Height];
texturePlayer.GetData(playerColorArray);
secondTexture.GetData(secondTextureArray);
```

and my question is how to get coordinates from Texture2D for each pixel which are Black in this Texture2D.

thanks for advance:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already have array of colors, so only one you need is to determinate coordinate in 2D of each from pixels in your arrays.

in [Riemers tutorial](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2D/Texture_to_Colors.php) (which I recommend), it's done like that:

```
    Color[,] colors2D = new Color[texture.Width, texture.Height];
     for (int x = 0; x < texture.Width; x++)
     {
         for (int y = 0; y < texture.Height; y++)
         {
             colors2D[x, y] = colors1D[x + y * texture.Width]; 
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally  I rather write extension methods:

```
public static class Texture2dHelper
{
    public static Color GetPixel(this Color[] colors, int x, int y, int width)
    {
        return colors[x + (y * width)];
    }
    public static Color[] GetPixels(this Texture2D texture)
    {
        Color[] colors1D = new Color[texture.Width * texture.Height];
        texture.GetData<Color>(colors1D);
        return colors1D;
    }
}
```

Comment: though i have to say.. im using this to generate a tile map from a color image...  but its not going so well.... its offset by 1width per row.... havent figured out where the fault is...